# How to call python UDF with streaming_python in CDH 4.4 pig?

Tags: python, hadoop-streaming

I am working on some python UDFs for my pig project.
In the first way, I prefer cPython instead of Jython because I want to use some mature
libraries such as numpy in python smoothly.

Here is a code slice  in my `pyudf.py` file:

```
from pig_util import outputSchema
import numpy as np

@outputSchema("T:double")
def std(input):
    input2 = [float(t[0]) for t in input]
    return np.std(input2)
```

In the pig script, I first register above python module with command:

```
Register 'pyudf.py' using streaming_python as myfuncs;
```

Then I can call the UDF in following part:

```
myfuncs.std(..)
```

The whole workflow can move forward without errors in Apache pig (1.2.1) installed on my desktop.
But the pig complains about `streaming_python` when I run the same code on our CDH platform:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. Could not load ScriptEngine: streaming_python for streaming_python (Supported langs: [javascript, jython, groovy, jruby]) : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: streaming_python
```

Does somebody know how the CDH works with streaming_python or any other solutions?

Thanks ahead!

Jamin--chenxm35@gmail.com

Comment: I think streaming_python needs at least pig 0.12. Are you sure you're not somehow using an older version when running on the cluster?

Comment: Thanks. I notice that we have Apache Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.5.0 installed. I will upgrade it and try later.